# Apache Cordova broadband

Tags: cordova, 3g, 4g, broadband

I haven't been able to find information about network restrictions and Cordova.
My question is
How can I prevent or restrict the use of mobile (3G/4G) broadband in a Apache Cordova 5 App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information). To check the connection type and act on that connection type. For example:

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    if(!states[Connection.WIFI] || !states[Connection.ETHERNET]) {
        alert('Your current connection type: ' + states[networkState] + ' is not supported in this app!');
        // Execute anything you want
        return;
    }
}

checkConnection();
```